# JavaScript slider with dynamic slide creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm looking for a JavaScript library, pure JS or JQuery-based, that will allow me to create a slider similar to AnythingSlider or http://basic-slider.com/demos/. The most important feature I'm looking for is the ability to dynamically append new slides and then trigger a transition to it. The ability to transition to any slide is also important.

Most libraries I've investigated require that you append the slide to an element then retrigger the slider. This is fine however most scripts I've tested change the current slide position or there's a noticeable change in the elements on screen that disrupt the user experience.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a personal fan of bx-slider. It's pretty basic, but it works really well. http://www.bxslider.com/

It just requires a basic div set up, and it's a plugin, so just call it from $('#myID').bxSlider();

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)? I have used this before and have never seen the problem you are describing (with retriggering the slider).